# In which process's virtual address space does memory-mapped files get allocated

Tags: windows, shared-memory

This question is asked in the context of *Microsoft Windows*.

If `Process A` uses `CreateFileMapping()` in Windows API to create a section object, and later on `Process B` access the same object, which process is in charge of hosting the section object???

If it's `Process A` the one hosting it, what happen when `Process A` is ended??? Does `Process B` able to continue to access the shared section object??? This second question only relevant provided it's indeed `Process A` the one hosting the shared section object.

Comment: The operating system hosts the section object.  It won't destroy it until all handles on it are closed.  There are not many practical cases where you can completely ignore one of the processes terminating unexpectedly.

Comment: When you said OS hosting it, does it mean it's in kernel space???

Comment: Yes, necessarily so when it needs to survive process termination.  The side-effects it produces, like the handle and the ability to map memory, are visible in userland.

Comment: Does that means if the section object is writable, there might be potential for a userland process to write into the kernel land memory???